# Is there any problems with Firewalls and Standard GWT-RPC?

Tags: java, gwt, firewall

I want to know if there is some problem if I use GWT-RPC for an Internet Application. Should I evaluate some other way to connect the client with the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems with Firewalls are not to be expected, because GWT-RPC simply uses HTTP POST. If you deploy the application on a server on port 80 (or 443 for https), it looks to a firewall just like any other communication with a web site.